# How can you override Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, overrides

Specifically I'm interested in potentially overriding `_isAllowed()` so that it defaults to `false` instead of `true`.  Most of the things I've found related to overriding controllers deal with how to override a specific route's controller, but I don't think that applies here.

The reason I want to do this is so that in case 3rd party modules that I haven't developed haven't implemented `_isAllowed()` in their controllers, they will default to not being accessible.

I know this is a pretty low-level change to make and could break things in the core, in which case I might not be able to do it.  But I'll obviously test that once I implement it.

I looked a bit at the logic inside `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match()` but not seeing anything that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a class that many other classes extend so it can't be easily overloaded (similar to base models or abstract classes).

If you really wanted to change this behavior you would have to copy and paste the entire source and place it inside of `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php`.

It is recommend to follow "proper" Magento convention and implement the `_isAllowed` method in your custom controller classes. For securing 3rd party modules, the above approach will work but you will purposely make upgrading more difficult. A "cleaner" approach would be as you mentioned to rewrite each specific route's controller. This could involve a lot of effort and time, you have to draw the line appropriately for each project.

Comment: +1 - Why change core code to cater for badly written extensions? Change the badly written extension to cater for core code. That's why we have Magento best practice rules.

Comment: Well specifically I'm talking about extensions that I *haven't* developed, such as the one mentioned in the post.  The idea behind this is to have a catchall so that the system defaults to not giving access unless it should.  To be honest I kind of wonder why the core doesn't return false by default.  But yes, local code pool is probably the answer here, I actually hadn't thought about that, I generally don't use the local code pool for anything.

Comment: @sparcksoft My guess is that this is one of those complex cases where Magento devs threw up their hands and didn't implement an approach because of the all the scenarios that come up with implementing ACL. You can define resources all day but (as you've noticed) you're free to actually map and implement them anyway you'd like. This is one of those scenarios where an AOP implementation in PHP would be really helpful.

Comment: +1. True.  As it is, ACLs can be prohibitively difficult to deal with for newer Magento devs, so maybe they err'd on the side of less configuration in this particular instance.