# I want to override mage/adminhtml/controller/Action.php?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to override in adminhtml controller action.php

I tried this

config.xml

```
<args>
                    <modules>
                        <Medma_MarketPlace before="Mage_Adminhtml">Medma_MarketPlace</Medma_MarketPlace>
                    </modules>
                </args>
```

Medma/Marketplace/controllers/adminhtml/action.php

My code is

```
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controller/Action.php";

class Medma_MarketPlace_Adminhtml_ActionController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_ActionController 
{
do somthing

}
```

but nothing happen I think i do something wrong.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, I suggest you can probably override a lower level admin controller instead of the entire Action.php file. Could you tell us what do you want to do ?

Comment: i want to  override  a  protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin');
        return true;

    }

Comment: I suggest you avoid doing this. The _isAllowed function takes care of security in your backend and overriding it this would make your store vulnerable to attack. I suggest you read this: http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make code and folder,file like follwing

Medma/Marketplace/controllers/**Adminhtml/ActionController.php**

```
class Medma_MarketPlace_Adminhtml_ActionController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
do somthing

}
```

**Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action** is a class that many other classes extend so it can't be easily overloaded (similar to base models or abstract classes).

If you really wanted to change this behavior you would have to copy and paste the entire source and place it inside of app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php.

It is recommend to follow "proper" Magento convention and implement the _isAllowed method in your custom controller classes. For securing 3rd party modules, the above approach will work but you will purposely make upgrading more difficult. A "cleaner" approach would be as you mentioned to rewrite each specific route's controller. This could involve a lot of effort and time, you have to draw the line appropriately for each project.

**Source :** [How can you override Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-can-you-override-mage-adminhtml-controller-action)

Comment: I make same folder structure

Comment: You have wriiten `adminhtml` in lowercase. make it exactly same

Comment: but nothing happen

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: adminhtml are exactly same no lower case

Comment: i want  protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        
        return true;

    }    in my extension

Comment: Check i have updated answer and put source answer link

Comment: thanks but i tried this if i put action.php in local folder its work but nothing happen when i override with my extension

Comment: What you want to override?